# How can I load jQuery generated content to another page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, window, load

**Expected Outcome:**

- Page A has HTML generated by jQuery.
- Page B needs to access the
  generated HTML on Page A.
- Page B successfully loads the generated
  HTML from Page A.

**Actual Outcome:**

- Page A has HTML generated by jQuery.
- Page B needs to access the generated HTML on Page A.
- Page B loads the content from Page A before the jQuery generates the new HTML.

My problem is that I am trying to pull in the generated content, but I can only pull the original HTML without the edits that were done by jQuery on document ready. Can I possibly pull a loaded version of an external page?

If this is possible what would be the appropriate method? ex: .load(), ajax, etc...

**Example:** (not the real markup but simplified for this purpose)

Page A is creating content like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('div#ABC').before('new content');
});
```

Comment: How are you generating this HTML, how is "Page B" attempting to access HTML from Page A? Are both pages on your site (i.e. same domain). Please provide some code examples on what you're trying

Comment: You need to get the HTML from page B, then perform whatever jQuery code amends it in page A after the load completes

Comment: I can't perform the same jQuery code on page B because the output is dependent on the content on Page A.

Basically I have a profile and depending on certain fields and values, there is a score given to the profile. I then need to pull back this score on another page. Unfortunately, I'm working with a CMS that doesn't give me a lot of flexibility to write this info back and access it that way.